# Remove user profile field

Tags: users, profiles

I'm looking for custom code to remove fields on user profile like you see in the pictures :
[image: remove what is in red color]
I would also like to replace Gravatar images with simple photos from the media library:

[image: remove what is in red color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

Create `wpse_admin_user.css` file and put it in your current theme, where `style.css` is:

```
tr.user-admin-color-wrap,
tr.user-admin-bar-front-wrap {
    display: none;
}
```

Add this code to your theme's functions.php:

```
function wpse_user_admin_script() {
    wp_register_style( 'wpse_admin_user_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/wpse_admin_user.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse_admin_user_css' );  
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_user_admin_script' );
```

#### Part 2

Install and activate [Custom User Profile Photo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-user-profile-photo/) plugin. You will be able to use pictures from media library.